# How to add/include a plugin in custom module joomla3.6.5

Tags: plugins, joomla, module

I am trying to add `jcomments` plugin within a custom module but it shows up as text on front page instead of loading the plugin

`{jcomments on}` is what I am putting in the module to include the plugin but its not working. Please advise.

Comment: you can refer to this page -  https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Module#onRenderModule

Comment: if you are still having this issue, perhaps post your question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/